# Why does this sign in form fail with no errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, erb

**TL;DR** Why does my user sign in form not create a new session/why does it fail without errors?

I'm pretty new to rails, and I'm having some confusion about user sign in forms that create new sessions. Essentially I can either sign the user in without creating a session, or signing in doesn't work and also doesn't create the session, but I don't get any errors.

I have tried:

1. Using whatever versions of `form_with` I can find, as well as `form_for` and `form_tag`.
2. Changing routes to anything and everything I can find in google.
3. Setting `SameSite="Lax"`.

new.html.erb

```
<h1>This is the new viewer page!</h1>

<%= form_with model: @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for :session, url: login_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :id %>
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
    <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:id][:password_digest])
            session[:id] = @user.id
            redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "User logged in"
        else
            redirect_to root_path, alert: "Something is wrong"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  get "/login", to: "sessions#new"
  post "/login", to: "sessions#create", via: :"post"
  delete "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy"

  root "users#new"
end
```

I'm aware that my flash message is useless for debugging, I also couldn't find anything straightforward on getting clearer debug output. the only thing I can find is a warning in the browser console talking about samesite=none so cookies will be rejected (i'm using firefox)

**EDIT**

The log when I try to submit the form

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-22 01:01:56 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"uUeDMYJKaxduZGqKJvaDiSO1bCFYDSIz6dcmp6CEeUNTYwBycJUb5l10K5KXcPZG2kOgdiK6pvPAKoDexwqSmA==", "session"=>{"id"=>"12"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT ?[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 1013)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-22 01:01:56 -0500
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.3ms | Allocations: 1302)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4667)
```

**EDIT 2**

log after making some changes:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-23 03:22:03 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"TIbECQO9vWQfDfmT89rGHKtdlamLXOUG3MYVgiB1bqZJJgp8C0h9LmFdyrLOS4HTmi/IHBp5bz0flz7BRU5wYA==", "user"=>{"id"=>"12"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/12
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2142)


Started GET "/users/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-23 03:22:03 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"12"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3:in `show'
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.3ms | Allocations: 96)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 8.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 4300)
```

Comment: You should find some entries in your log-files (in the "log" directory). Can you share these, too?

Comment: What do you mean by "fail without errors"? Or "doesn't work and also doesn't create the session"? What exactly do see happen?

Comment: @Felix I'll post it when I have access to my computer again tomorrow.
@TomLord So I can use `form_for @user, url_login_path` to get the user signed in, but according to the browser inspector it doesn't create a new session. That being said, any other arrangement of `form_for` or `form_with` just seem to not do anything when you click submit. No error, no redirect, no new session

Comment: Is there somewhere where you load the currenet user from the sesion?

Comment: @Felix I posted the log entries for when I try to submit the form

Comment: @maxpleaner All of the code here is pretty much what I have (or at least most of/all of the things that I've touched), so if something is missing let me know and I'll try to add it in!

Comment: @max I have tried it on chrome and firefox to test both and see if it was an individual browser problem. If it's a cookie problem it's something I still need to learn how to fix

Comment: I just am not convinced the code you've shown doesn't work. At some point in your controllers you have to load current user from the session right? Maybe that's the part which is messed up. Sessions are not supposed to be readable by the client, by the way. They are encrypted.

Comment: @maxpleaner by 'not working' I mean that i get the flash alert that says "something is wrong". I would think that means something is wrong around the `authenticate` in the session controller. Also, I don't mean that the user should be able to read the session, I mean when you use the inspector to look at cookies or sessions none are created when the form is submitted

Comment: @schnondle In the logs you can see which parameters are passed to the controller, and which query it does. There are no parameters like password etc. And you might want to look into strong parameters (usually your controller whitelists the parameters explicitely): https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: @Felix So I undid a bunch of changes and now it signs in, but the flash at the top of the screen says "user NOT saved", but this log file looks like maybe it created a session? I'm definitely confused, is this working correctly, and if yes, why do I get that flash alert?

Comment: @schnondle there are a number of issues with your code - `params[:id][:password_digest]` is wrong, for starters. You don't pass a `password_digest` param from your form at all, and it's definitely not going to be nested under `id`. Also, you are setting `session[:id]` and clearing `session[:user_id]` - not the same. I would recommend learning to use a debugger gem (e.g. `pry`) and going through a tutorial on auth again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing is happening is that the code is completely broken.

Look at the parameters in the log:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"TIbECQO9vWQfDfmT89rGHKtdlamLXOUG3MYVgiB1bqZJJgp8C0h9LmFdyrLOS4HTmi/IHBp5bz0flz7BRU5wYA==", "user"=>{"id"=>"12"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Now look at your create method:

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:id][:password_digest])
        session[:id] = @user.id
        redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "User logged in"
    else
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "Something is wrong"
    end
end
```

There is no `params[:id]` nor any password passed anywhere in the parameters. `params[:id][:password_digest]` is also always going to be nil. So if `@user && @user.authenticate(params[:id][:password_digest])` is NEVER going to be true.

`params[:id][:password_digest]` is straight up bonkers as you generate password digests with a encryption algorithm like bcrypt from a plain-text password and save it in the database. Never would you actually take a password digest from a user.

Instead when signing a user in you take a plain-text password and pass that to bcrypt which tells you if the password digest matches any of the hashes generated for that string. If it does `.authenticate` returns true.

Having the user supply and id instead of something like an email or username is also strange.

What you actually want is something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
end
```

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /login
  def new; end

  # POST /login
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if @user&.autenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
      render :new
    end
  end

  # DELETE /logout
  def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/sessions/_form.html.erb
# this creates a form with "unnested" inputs
<%= form_with url: login_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :email %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

```
# app/views/sessions/new.html.erb
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Now the user signs in and the correct flash displays. I have one more question: is there a way to see anything about the session? (for example how in the browser inspector you can inspect cookies)

Comment: Since the session cookie is encrypted you can't read it. What you can do is use the meta_request gem together with RailsPanel but I would really consider writing tests to cover this instead.